# mongorestore warning when supplying username and password

Tags: mongodb

I am using the mongorestore command line to restore a gzip dump to a database.

Security is enabled on my MongoDB instance, and therefore I need to provide username and password to the command line so I am authorized to complete the said restore.

But for MongoDB to authenticate the user, the `-d` option is also supplied for MongoDB to know what database to use to authenticate the user.

Because I use the `-d`, mongorestore complains with the following:

```
the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from
a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future;
use --nsInclude instead
```

I tried using `--nsInclude` instead of `-d` as suggested, however when I do so, mongorestore is no longer able to authenticate the user and the operation fails.

Here is how the full command line looks like:

```
mongorestore -h "myhost" -u myUserName -p myPassword -d myDatabaseName --drop --archive=dump.zip --gzip --nsInclude myDatabaseName.*
```

So how are we supposed to stop using the deprecated `-d` option and still be able to authenticate for the restore to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`--authenticationDatabase`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-authenticationdatabase) instead of `-d`.

[`-d` or `--db`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-db) specifies the database to restore *into*. For auth purposes, these are not the parameters you're looking for.

The `-d` parameter is superseded by [`--nsFrom`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-nsfrom), [`--nsTo`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-nsto), and [`--nsInclude`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-nsinclude) in MongoDB 3.4 and newer, since they are more descriptive of the intent.